# Hiding buttons design

Tags: button, hidden

So I have a home page with a number of button links on, but I need certain ones to be hidden depending on who is logged in.

My initial thought was to save several different copies of my home page and then send the user to the appropriate one when they log in.

Can anyone suggest a neater way to do this?

Comment: we need way more information. What is your backend system / code / framework. What have you already tried ?

Comment: Im using php scripts to communicate with a SQL server. For the front end Im using html, js and css. I have tried having different versions of my home page and then used a php script to check the database to see what the user is allowed to see the redirect them to appropriate version of my home page

Comment: Im also happy to use ajax

Comment: How do you validate if a user is logged in or not? Do you return a user object to your sites?

Comment: with a $_SESSION variable

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to have different sites if it's only about changing some buttons and not the complete context.

Since code examples are missing i'll have some assumptions.

Let's say if your use is logged in you have set

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] === true
```

Then just write your html like this

```
<!-- ... -->
<p>This is visible to everyone</p>

<?php if ( isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] === true ) { ?>
<p>Only logged in users see this</p>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( !isset($_SESSION['logged_in]) ) {?>
<p>Only not logged in users see this</p>
<?php }?>
```

**EDIT**

This of course requires you to run not html but php pages. Don't forget to call session_start(); before using sessions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I should have been more clear but what I actually meant is that each user has a different authorisations and so they see different buttons when logged in.